# LTE Bands for European Galaxy S7 (SM-G935F) while in the US

Tags: samsung, mobile-network, 4g, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

I have a European model of Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge (SM-G935F), 32GB version.

It is a SIM free phone, not locked to any particular vendor. I am aware of region lock, but from my understanding it should be OK, since I have been making calls for a few months with it in Europe.

According to GSM Arena, these are the bands supported by this model:

> LTE band 1(2100), 2(1900), 3(1800), 4(1700/2100), 5(850), 7(2600),
>   8(900), 12(700), 13(700), 17(700), 18(800), 19(800), 20(800),
>   25(1900), 26(850), 28(700), 38(2600), 39(1900), 40(2300), 41(2500) -
>   G935F

Currently I am using EE carrier in the UK, supporting bands 3 and 7.
AT&T in the states should support bands 2, 4, 5, 17.

My assumption is, because my phone supports these bands, I should have no trouble using LTE in the US?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You'll be absolutly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from Note 5, Samsung has blessed their flagships with near-iPhone level of international cellular capabilities, as shown in the specs you've read. VoLTE and Wi-Fi calling might take a hit, but as long as AT&T is willing to offer and activate a new SIM for you, you should be fine using LTE itself.